# Why aren't children of flex element being displayed with the width I set for it?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got 5 children `div`s inside a parent `div` whose display is set to `flex`.

I've given the children a width of `100px` each, but they are only being rendered at 1/5th of the width of the parent `div`.

I've set the parent `div` with `overflow: scroll` in the hopes it will make the children expand to the set size, but it does now. How do I get the children `div`s to be the width I give it?

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought 100 * 5 = 500 not 350 ?

Comment: On ".child",  set minimum width to 100px and On parent set overflow-x to scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `flex-shrink` to `0`, so to the flexbox won't shrink the children to fit the parent's width:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 5px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child always-show"></div>
</div>
```

Another option is to set to use the `flex` shortcut to set growth 0/shrink 0 /basis 100px, and remove the width declaration:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.child {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child always-show"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: shrink will die in some new browser

Comment: Shrink is part of the flexbox standard, and supported by all browsers the support flex. Why should it die in a new browser?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property

Comment: The `flex` shorthand contains the shrink. It doesn't replace it.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.child {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child always-show"></div>
</div>
```

Just posting an alternative solution to "flex-shrink" if needed, Set min-width on "child" elements to 100px.

Comment: hmm why does `min-width` work but `width` doesn't?

Comment: @CodyBugstein When you speicfy "width", it can still be shrinked or scaled down based on the parent element's properties. But when you specify "min-width" it takes precedence over all the other calculations.

Comment: @CodyBugstein because it was defined to work like that in the Flexbox context: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/8620333